# Realtor broke contract without notifying

Tags: contract-law, liability, real-estate, pennsylvania

I have been in the process of buying a house for the last months and my realtor had been acting strange as she kept arguing for the Seller.

Now First off I live in PA so Dual Agency is allowed, however we have an explicit contract that says if Dual Agency were to occur that her employer would appoint a separate Realtor to represent the buyer. This did not occur

Now when signing the final loan paper work, previous paper work did not have realtors signatures in them at time of signing, I see that mine is listed for both buyer and seller. It also turns out that the initial estimates given were dramatically off for closing costs and monthly payments provided by the realtor with even the property taxes being incorrect.

I intend to close on the house as I've already signed all the loan paper work, but is there anything that can be done about a Realtor that breaks contract? Also second question would it be better to seek a personal or Real estate attorney in such situations as this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I intend to close on the house as I've already signed all the loan
>   paper work, but is there anything that can be done about a Realtor
>   that breaks contract?

You have probably waived your claim if you proceed with the deal knowing about the Realtor's conduct. What would your damages be? Could you have mitigated them by not agreeing to the deal?

> Also second question would it be better to seek a personal or Real
>   estate attorney in such situations as this?

Lawyers aren't that specialized. I would not recognize a "personal" attorney as something necessarily different from a "Real estate attorney" and the questions involved are not so complex that a general practice attorney couldn't handle them.

Familiarity with real estate issues would be desirable (e.g. you wouldn't want to hire someone whose practice was exclusively as a criminal defense attorney or a personal injury lawyer, or a patent lawyer, for this task), but a great many lawyers who describe their practices differently would have the relevant experience and knowledge.

Comment: Thank you for the information, for me I put in my 2 months notice and would have needed to immediately find another place if I don't go through with the deal, but that's just extra info. I will find a personal consult then.